# c++ instantiate several classes if a condition is true

Tags: c++

Is there a way I can make this work?

I want to create 5 instances of bank if age is greater than 17, but I am getting this error:

> [Error] no matching function for call to 'Bank::Bank()'

I need to get this right for my assignment in school.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Bank{
    string Fullname;
    string StateOfOrigin;
    int Age;

     public:

        Bank(string name, string state, int age){
            Fullname = name;
            StateOfOrigin = state;
            Age = age;
        }
        string getname(){
            return Fullname;
        }
        string getstate(){
            return StateOfOrigin;
        }
        int getage(){
            return Age;
        }

};

int main(){
    Bank customer[20];
    int x,y,z,age;
    string name;
    string state;
    cout<<"==============================="<<endl;
    cout<<"Welcome To Hojma Bank.Plc"<<endl;
    cout<<"How many accounts do you want to create? \n";
    cin>>y;


    for(int k = 0; k < y; k++){
        cout<<"Please input your fullname"<<endl;
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"Please input your state of origin"<<endl;
        cin>>state;
        cout<<"Please input your age";cout<<endl;
        cin>>age;
        if(age >= 18){
            Bank customer[y](name,state,age);
            cout << customer[y].getname();  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Programming by guessing doesn't work. What does `Bank customer[y](name,state,age)` do?

Answer (score 1):

```
Bank customer[20];
```

Here you default-construct twenty `Bank` objects (oddly called `customer`??). Or, at least, you tried to, but your `Bank` class has no default constructor. Neither should it, from what I can tell.

```
Bank customer[y](name,state,age);
cout << customer[y].getname();
```

Here I guess you tried to "declare" individual array elements, but it doesn't work like that.

Also your usage of `y` is wrong; you can accept `y` maximum, but you probably meant to use the current loop counter value, `k`. That's broken too because you have a filter on age so you might skip some array elements.

---

Why not use a nice tasty `std::vector`, and add new customers at will? Then you can also get rid of those confusing `int`s, half of which you're not even using.

```
int main()
{
    int y = 0;

    cout << "===============================\n";
    cout << "Welcome To Hojma Bank.Plc\n";
    cout << "How many accounts do you want to create?" << endl;
    cin >> y;

    std::vector<Bank> customers;

    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        int age;
        string name;
        string state;

        cout << "Please input your full name" << endl;
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Please input your state of origin" << endl;
        cin >> state;
        cout << "Please input your age" << endl;
        cin >> age;

        if (age >= 18){
            customers.emplace_back(name,state,age);
            cout << customer.back().getname();
        }
    }
}
```

You could do with some error checking on your user input, too. And rename that class to `Customer`.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an array of objects (`Bank customer[20]`), the class needs to have a default constructor. Just define something like this:

```
Bank() : Fullname(""), StateOfOrigin(""), Age(0) {}
```

Comment: This is a poor solution. What, semantically, does a bank with no name, "state of origin" or age _mean_?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Agreed, but that was not my point. By the way, `Bank`is also a pretty poor name for a class that represents a bank customer.

Comment: Agreed, that's fairly terrible.